# Readline in C and stop when limit is reached

Tags: c, input, logic

I have a function `int getLine(char s[],int lim)` which reads the next line of input,as someone might assume, and returns it's length as an integer. Specifically

```
int getLine(char s[],int lim)
{
int i;
char c;

for(i=0; i<lim-1&&(c=getchar())!='\n'; ++i)
{
    s[i]=c;
}
s[i]='\0';

return i;
}
```

So far so good, the issue is that I don't want the user to be able to add as many characters as he wants,but I want him to be limited, and so I have added this `int lim` but as I soon realize, this does not co-operates good with other loops, for example

```
int main()
{
double len;
int currentLength=0;
char s[20];
printf("Give an integer N with 1%cN%c30 to make a NxN array\n",242,242);

do
{
    printf("N=");
}
while(!((currentLength=getLine(s,20))>0&&try_Parse(s,&len)&&(len - (int)len)==0&&len>=1&&len<=30));

int real_len = (int) len;
double A[real_len*real_len];
for(int i=0; i<real_len; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j<real_len; ++j)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Give A[%d][%d]=",i+1,j+1);
        }
        while(!((currentLength=getLine(s,20))>0&&try_Parse(s,&A[i*real_len+j])));


return 0;
}
```

When one runs this code and gives input for N something like that (N=0.0000000000000000000001) or even more zeros, the program reads the first 20 says ok we reached the limit, returns 19 and does the same with the rest until it has no more to read.

My question is:
How can I stop it from reading an input that exceeds this limit ?

(try_Parse is a function that I have created, don't mind it)

Comment: Use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead of your homemade `getline?` function. Or rather `getline` replace the body of your `getline` function by a wrapper using `fgets`, (~5 lines of code).

Comment: for one i dont know how to use it (of course i will learn) but I would like to solve my problem the way it is already built . But thanks anyway !

Comment: If you reach the limit of the buffer in `getLine()` and have not yet seen a newline, add code to read to the next newline, discarding the characters: `int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') ;` (empty loop body).

Comment: interesting idea... I will try it and i will let you know .. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment, if your code doesn't read a newline before it runs out of space, it should 'gobble' the rest of the line of input.  Your code also needs to be more careful about EOF — `getchar()` returns an `int` and not a `char` (because it has to be able to return any valid `char` value and also a distinct `EOF` value).

That leads to code such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getLine(char s[],int lim);

int getLine(char s[], int lim)
{
    int i;
    int c;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();

    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[20];
    int n;

    printf("Give an integer N with 1 <= N <= 30 to make a NxN array: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    while ((n = getLine(s, sizeof(s))) > 0)
    {
        long num = strtol(s, 0, 0);
        printf("Got length: %ld\n", num);
        printf("Again: ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The loop is slightly different from what was suggested in the comment, but achieves the right result.

The test code is careless about the way it uses the return value from `strtol()`; testing that it succeeded is a much more delicate task.  However, it suffices for a test program.

Example use (program name `rl13`):

```
$ ./rl13
Give an integer N with 1 <= N <= 30 to make a NxN array: 23
Got length: 23
Again: 0000000000000000000000001
Got length: 0
Again: 0
Got length: 0
Again: 
$
```